# Filtrar usuarios por un determinado rol Identity - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, identity

Estoy usando **ASP.NET Identity 2.2.2** no Core para utilizar autenticaciones y autorizaciones en una aplicacion MVC. Quiero obtener una lista de usuarios pero por un determinado rol. Obtuve la lista pero me esta costando hacer el filtro. Les muestro mi controlador:

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }
    public RoleManager<IdentityRole> RoleManager { get; private set; }
    public ApplicationDbContext contexto { get; private set; }
    public AdminController()
    {
        contexto = new ApplicationDbContext();
        UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(contexto));
        RoleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(contexto));
    }

    public AdminController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        RoleManager = roleManager;
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> GestionarClientes()
    {
        return View(await UserManager.Users.ToListAsync());
    }
}
```

No se como usar un **Where** en la vista **`GestionarClientes`**, que me filtre el Roles donde sean "**Clientes**"
Alguna sugerencia? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener los Usuarios en un determinado Rol debes utilizar el método **`GetUsersInRoleAsync()`**.

El código sería el siguiente:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GestionarClientes()
{
    return View(await UserManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Clientes"));
}
```

**Nota:** El método `GetUsersInRoleAsync()` devuelve un `List<ApplicationUser>`.

Comment: Hola Rafael, no me encuentra ningun metodo con el nombre GetUsersInRoleAsync(). Usando ctrl+. no me da ninguna solucion. Que puede ser?

Comment: @iMSn20:  Está en el Namespace **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity**. Utiliza **Ctrl .** (punto).

Comment: Si lo hice, pero no me daba ninguna solucion. Lo agrego manualmente y ahora tnego problemas en las primeras lineas donde declaro las propiedades UserManager y RoleManager, ya que tengo el namespace **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity** y me dice que es una relacion ambigua entre ambas. Si elimino **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity** me da problemas y encima tampoco me aparece ese metodo si lo agrego a **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity**

Comment: @iMSn20: Ok entendido, desinstálalo. No estás trabajando con .NET Core, deberías haberlo indicado en la pregunta. Que versión de Identity y  .NET Framework utilizas?

Comment: Identity 2.2.2 y NET Framework 4.7.2. Disculpa, ahora lo aclaro